# Documents.get API and Display Document's Content in React.js app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-docs-api

I have a project where I need to display some google docs documents in react.js app.
To achieve this first I tried to use some packages such as react-google-docs-viewer, however, it didn't work as I expected.
After searching I found documents.get API from google-docs-api but I couldn't figure out how can I display the docuemnts' content from the response of documents.get call which seems a little confusing.
Is there a efficient way to achieve this goal?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi there @Batu! I don't understand where you need help, could you please clarify your question? Do you need help using the Docs API and its data? Or do you need help inserting that data into the React.js app?

Comment: Hi @Jacques-GuzelHeron I need help when inserting the data into the React.js app.